# How to do a drag and drop in mvc with jquery or js

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a web page:
[image]

then I do a click arrow right is changed next artikel details and then I do a click arrow left is displaied a preview artikel. I want to do this now then do a drag and drop to left and right to change the artikel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be what you are looking for ==> [James Lin's Blog on js swipe demo](http://james.lin.net.nz/2010/09/27/javascript-swipe-demo-works-both-with-finger-ipad-and-mouse-pc/).